# Obter memória total do sistema e componentes do sistema em java

Tags: java, memória, cpu

Existe algum método simples ou confiável para pegar a memória total do computador e/ou os componentes ou modelos dos componentes do computador?

Pesquisei bastante e a unica coisa que eu encontrei foi alguns artigos falando sobre a classe `com.sun.management.OperatingSystemMXBean` porém ela esta "protegida" e isso gera um erro nas IDEs e não sei se é seguro ignorar este erro, a final de contas se esta dando algum erro é porque algo esta errado.

Comment: Tentou usar `java.lang.Runtime`? https://stackoverflow.com/a/12807848

Comment: Runtime retorna as informações do "programa" atual, não sei explicar bem mas isso não retorna a memória do computador.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depois de dar uma estudada consegui desenvolver um método que não gere erros e funcione perfeitamente usando Reflexão e a classe `OperatingSystemMXBean` do `java.lang`

```
private long getFreeMemoryComputer() {
    try {
        OperatingSystemMXBean system = ManagementFactory.getOperatingSystemMXBean();
        Method getFreeMemory = system.getClass().getMethod("getFreePhysicalMemorySize");
        getFreeMemory.setAccessible(true);
        return (long) getFreeMemory.invoke(system);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        return -1;
    }
}

private long getTotalMemoryComputer() {
    try {
        OperatingSystemMXBean system = ManagementFactory.getOperatingSystemMXBean();
        Method getTotalMemory = system.getClass().getMethod("getTotalPhysicalMemorySize");
        getTotalMemory.setAccessible(true);
        return (long) getTotalMemory.invoke(system);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        return -1;
    }
}
```